# How can I tell the content type of an empty list in java

Tags: java, list, arraylist

Say I have the following two empty lists

```
List<String> obj1 = new ArrayList<String>();
List< Integer> obj2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

without foreknowledge, how can I tell which is of type `String` and which is of type `Integer`? (Please, never mind why I need this info).

Here I can no longer do

```
if (!list.isEmpty() && list.get(0) instanceof String)
```

as the list is empty.

Comment: If it is a local variable, **you can't**. And basically you now have to change _Please, never mind why I need this info_.

Comment: This is not possible. I also find that situations like this may also point to a design flaw.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, I am just trying to avoid the barrage of comments about what it's for, etc. But the list is relayed through the update method of an observer, where the observable can send either content type.

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3403909/get-generic-type-of-class-at-runtime

Comment: You're declaring the lists explicitly yourself, so you _have_ foreknowledge in this example (ie you know `obj1` contains Strings). If the lists are passed to your objects at runtime, you cannot determine this without a hideous `instanceof`.

Comment: I agree with @Leon that your design smells bad.

Comment: You've explained what you want to do with it: _But the list is relayed through the update method of an observer, where the observable can send either content type._, but not why.

Comment: If you tell us more about what you need to do, people will be able to suggest a better design quickly.

Comment: Even if the `List` is not empty, the fact that one element is `instanceof` `X` does not prove that the `List` is a `List<X>`

Comment: Collections don't have a content type (Check out for example the source of ArrayList, its all Object internally). So you can't check it. Pass the type along with the list if you need it.

Answer (score -2):

This is not a correct approach, but it works!

```
List<String> obj1 = new ArrayList<>();    
List<Integer> obj2 = new ArrayList<>();

Object o = new Integer(7);
try{
  obj1.add((String) o);
  System.out.println("This is a list of integer!");
}catch(ClassCastException ex){
  System.out.println("This is not a integer list!");
}
```

Comment: If it's not correct, why share it?

Comment: Simply executing `(String)new Integer(7)` guarantees you a class cast exception no matter what.

Comment: You can assume here that OP receives a `List<?>` in their observer method.